# How can I read bluetooth data with ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, gazebo, kuka, bluetooth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a KUKA KR5 arc HW-2 manipulator in Gazebo, I created the URDF model and all the necessary drivers to be able to move it, what I would like to know is if it is possible to use an Xbox Series S controller to be able to move its joints. I understand that the new Xbox controls communicate via bluetooth but I really don't know how to obtain the data sent by their different buttons and triggers with ROS. Is there a package for that or a rospy or roscpp function that can be used to read what is being sent through a bluetooth channel?

If someone has managed to do something similar to what I'm looking for, I'd really appreciate it if you could guide me, it's for the development of a school project, it doesn't matter if a wired Xbox controller, PlayStation controller or any other bluetooth controller was used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399953/how-can-i-read-bluetooth-data-with-ros-noetic?/) by [LuisEFA1998](https://answers.ros.org/users/99578/luisefa1998/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS categorizes such devices as joysticks. If you configure linux properly, the OS sees the bluetooth-controller as a serial port which sends a stream of characters.

Start your investigation here: http://wiki.ros.org/joystick_drivers

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LuisEFA1998](https://answers.ros.org/users/99578/luisefa1998/) on 2022-05-03**:
Thanks a lot bro, I'll check that ROS package.